# jquery: a better way to tie an animation to scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
var AddFootnoteScrollIndicator = function(){
    $('.mobileFootnote').on('scroll touchmove', function (event) {
        var scrollTop = that.$mobileFootnote.scrollTop();                
        if (scrollTop <= 20){
            var opacity = 1 - (scrollTop/20);
            $('.scroll-down-indicator').css({'opacity': opacity });
        }
    });
};
```

As the user scrolls down, the indicator slowly fades out until it is gone. They scroll back up, the indicator slowly re-appears. They stop in the middle, the indicator is half-visible.

Code works fine, but modifying the opacity via `.css()` seems expensive. Is there a more clever way of doing this via css or...

I don't want to delay the `.on()` polling because the animation needs to respond quickly to the scroll.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to scroll events, modifying the css via javascript is the only way to go. There is not a way with pure CSS to detect scroll positions like you can with media queries and screen sizes.

The jquery `css()` function is setting the `element.style.opacity` property under the hood. You are only one short abstraction layer from the actual element property, so it is not "expensive".

The most costly part of that call would be the `$('.scroll-down-indicator')` selector, as it has to perform a DOM traversal to find elements with the class name.

Comment: Thank for the answer.